# Filtering articles by author in url

Tags: joomla-4.x, url, content-filtering

Can I get articles from a specific author in this way in joomla 4?

```
/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=87&layout=blog&filter[author_id]=42
```

This method works with Tags, but I would need it by author name or user_id